# selecting according to two condintions

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure it out why this does not work. The `df2` dataframe should contain all the data from df which match two conditions..

```
df2 = df.loc[df['area'] == "north" & df['product'] == "a"]
```

Comment: please provide an exemplar dataframe or at least the head of your dataframe.

Comment: You need parentheses as per the duplicate question: `df.loc[(df['area'] == "north") & (df['product'] == "a")]`

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
df2=df.loc[df['area'] == "north"].loc[df['product'] == "a"]
```

or

```
df2 = df[(df["area"] == "north") & (df["product"] == "a")]
```

Would do the job.